# How to get Entitas components from gameObject.getEntityLink()

Tags: unity, entity-system, entity-component

I'm new to Entitas. I have a `DamageSystem` that should `Physics.Raycast()` toward the target and if tag is enemy it should reduce enemy health.

I have `HealthComponent`:

```
public class HealthComponent: IComponent{

public float value;

}
```

In `DamageSystem` I wanna do something like:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(target, direction, out hit)){

     tag.gameObject.entity.health.value = currentHealth - damage ;

}
```

But after `Physics.Raycast()`, I have  only  the `gameObject` and `getEntityLink()` method that return `EntityLink` without actual components... I guess that `getEntityLink()` returns only abstract components, and there is no way to get `HealthComponent` from `EntityLink`?

Does someone know how to get components from `EntityLink`, in a clean manner? 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
  if(Physics.Raycast(target, direction, out hit)){

        var target = hit.transform.gameObject.GetEntityLink().entity;

            HealthComponent component = ((HealthComponent)target.GetComponent(GameComponentsLookup.Health));
             //reduce health
            component.value -= weapon.weaponDamage;

            target.ReplaceComponent(GameComponentsLookup.Health, component);


    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, You can read about Physics.Raycast [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).
Second of all, You need to store the data that the Physics.Raycast outputs.

I will keep it really simple but you should use layermasks with Raycast to avoid hitting colliders and triggers that can stop the raycast from hitting the target.

How layers work can be found [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).
More about Layermasks you can read [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html).

So the code should look something like this:

```
void Shoot(int damage) //Function that shoots raycast
{
  RaycastHit hit; //variable to store raycast data
  Enemy enemy; //Enemy component that will be stored and used

  if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit)) //We shoot the ray
  {
    if(hit.collider.tag == "Enemy") //We check if what we hit has an Enemy Tag
       enemy = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>(); //We store that component to use later.

    if(enemy != null) //We check if the component is existing and not empty
       enemy.TakeDamage(damage); //We apply damage based on value the function input damage
  }
}
```

As for the health system there should be a function that takes the damage.

```
private int _health = 100; //Private variable so it won't be changed from outside the script


public void TakeDamage(int damage) //A simple function to apply damage, its public so other scripts can access it and use it to damage the health system
{
  _health -= damage; //We apply the damage that was given to the function.
}
```

Comment: I wanna get EntityLink() ,
 not c#-script